# ATmega8 to MCP23S17 SPI I/O Expander not working

Tags: atmega, c, spi

Since three days I'm having the problem that I can not talk to my [`MCP23S17`](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf) SPI I/O Expander from my [`ATmega8`](http://akizukidenshi.com/download/ATMEGA8-16PU-ND.pdf).

I've double checked my circuit and I'm sure that I did that right.

I want to apologize in advance for that much code but I really double checked everything already and I hope that someone might see what I don't ..

The problem is that I'm sure that my code is also correct. Please assume all necessary headers as included (I'm not a C-beginner is what I want to say).

This is the main function:

```
#define PB_SPI_SS_MCP23S17 PB2
#define PB_SPI_MOSI        PB3
#define PB_SPI_SCK         PB5

// Port C output pins
#define PC_HEARTBEAT       PC4

static void delay(double ms)
{
#ifndef SIMULATOR
  _delay_ms(ms);
#endif
}

void Spi_InitializeAsMaster(void)
{
  SPCR =  (1 << SPE)   // Enable SPI
        | (1 << MSTR)  // Set as master
        | (1 << CPOL)  // Clock polarity (falling edge is leading)
        | (1 << SPR0); // SPI clock rate select fck/16   
  SPSR = SPSR & 0xFE;  // Clear "Double SPI Speed" bit
}

void Spi_Send(char cData)
{
    // Start transmission
    SPDR = cData;
    // Wait for transmission complete
    while( !(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)) );
}

int main (void)
{
  delay(100);

  DDRC = (1 << PC_HEARTBEAT);
  DDRB = (1 << PB_SPI_SS_MCP23S17) | (1 << PB_SPI_MOSI) | (1 << PB_SPI_SCK);

  Spi_InitializeAsMaster();

  Mcp23s17 mcp;
  Mcp23s17_Initialize(&mcp, (int*)&PORTB, PB_SPI_SS_MCP23S17);
  Mcp23s17_SetPortDirection(&mcp, IODIRA, 0xFF);
  Mcp23s17_SetPortDirection(&mcp, IODIRB, 0xFF);

  while(1) 
  {    
    PORTC = ~PORTC;

    Mcp23s17_SetOutputPin(&mcp, GPIOA, 0xFF);
    Mcp23s17_SetOutputPin(&mcp, GPIOB, 0xFF);     
    delay(200);        
    Mcp23s17_SetOutputPin(&mcp, GPIOA, 0x00);
    Mcp23s17_SetOutputPin(&mcp, GPIOB, 0x00);    
    delay(200);
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the [`MCP23S17`](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf):

```
static void Mcp23s17_Write(Mcp23s17 * self, char address, char data)
{
  SPI_SELECT(self->spi)
  delay(20);
  Spi_Send(self->write_opcode);
  Spi_Send(address);
  Spi_Send(data);
  SPI_UNSELECT(self->spi)
  delay(20);
}

void Mcp23s17_Initialize(Mcp23s17 *self, int * sfr_address, int sfr_pin)
{
  self->spi.sfr_address = sfr_address;
  self->spi.sfr_pin     = sfr_pin;

  self->write_opcode    = 0x40;
  self->read_opcode     = 0x40 | 1;

  SPI_UNSELECT(self->spi)  
  Mcp23s17_Write(self, IOCON, IOCON_BYTE_MODE | IOCON_HAEN);
}

void Mcp23s17_SetPortDirection(Mcp23s17 * self, Mcp23s17Portdirection port, char direction)
{
  Mcp23s17_Write(self, (char)port , direction);
}
```

I'd be very thankful for any help! Please let me know if you need more information.
Best regards.

Comment: Do you have a scope or logic analyzer or logic probe you can use to check the SPI signals?  Can you drastically slow it down and put LEDs on them?  Does the MCP23S17 have an ID register you could read to verify bus operation?  Does your heartbeat at least work?

Comment: Yes, the heartbeat works. No, unfortunately I don't have a logic analyzer but I think I'm going to get one .. All I can see (using delay) is that the `SS` pin gets pulled down as the `MCP23S17` gets selected using an LED. You mean if I can observe something on the `MOSI` pin? I'm not quite sure. If I connect an LED to it, it is always high.

Comment: What would happen if I wrote `while(1) { SPDR = cData; }` ? Would `MOSI` let the LED shine or not? Or wouldn't that work at all?

Comment: @ChrisStratton What I can observe for `while(1) { Spi_Write(0x00); }` is that the LED shines less bright. I assume this makes sense as it sends only zero-bytes.

Comment: If there's any way you can justify it, a $400 rigol or similar benchtop LCD scope is a very versatile tool - most of the little gadget ones cheaper than that have serious usability issues like missing alias filters or triggering indicators and bad probes.  A generic CY7C68013A logic analyzer is dirt cheap and quite powerful with the free, open source Sigrok driving it, but will take some experience to set up and use apply.

Comment: In theory, at zero cost but time you could write a "bit-bang" software-manipulating-IOs SPI implementation that was so slow that you could watch the operation on LEDs (or even manually clock it with a software debounced pushbutton).  Once that worked, you could then scale up the clock to a fair fraction of what the hardware SPI engine can do, and perhaps use the experience to guide the transition to using the hardware SPI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in incompatible SPI modes. MCP23S17, like most peripheral chips, supports modes 0,0 and 1,1. But on the ATMega, you have set CPOL=1,CPHA=0.

Comment: I've aready tried CPOL=0,CPHA=0 but it still doesn't work ..